# What is the equilent of Mage::app()->getResponse()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','503 Service Unavailable') ->sendResponse(); in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1.3

What is the equivalent of **Magento 1** to **Magento 2**?

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()
        ->setHeader('HTTP/1.1','503 Service Unavailable')
        ->sendResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller you can use following;

```
public function execute()
{      
    $this->getResponse()
        ->setStatusCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http::STATUS_CODE_503)
        ->setContent('503 Service Unavailable');
    return ;
}
```

EDIT:

You can try injecting `\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory` in your class and calling 
`$this->response->setHeader('HTTP/1.1', '503 Service Unavailable', true);` (if your object is $response) and return it at end.

Comment: Yup.. Okay. I want to write this code inside Model file. How can I do that?

Comment: I think models are just for accessing db, but stll I am updating my answer check if it is working

Comment: Thanks for reply. it's asking `$type` is missing. from `$this->resultF->create()->setHeader('HTTP/1.1', '503 Service Unavailable', true);` code